# How to select a row in a html table without using a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database

Okay so i have a large html table(over 120 rows) and a search bar. The problem is that these rows dont have buttons in them and i want the user to be able to select them. I got this data from an internet database. I dont want to have to go through 120 rows of html table putting a button in each one(also im only working with a section of the original table which has over 3000 rows, so going through all of it is really not an option). Anyway how can i make the user able to select a cell/row and get its value without changing the original table in html?

Comment: what do you mean select it? and do what?

Comment: I mean to get its value

Comment: so you click on a cell and what do you expect to happen? tell us the expected result. do you want to alert the value inside the cell what?

Comment: The value is stored in this: localStorage.setItem("name", [value from cell]);

Answer (score 8):

you can always put have a click event on the td/tr and do whatever you want the function which get called

```js
var elements= document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++)
{
(elements)[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   alert(this.innerHTML);
});
}
```

```css
td:hover{
background-color:gray;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with pure js?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "select" a cell or a row without adding other controls to the table you could add an onclick handler and do something inside it (for example, change its background color, print a message, or anything you want)